# How certain page element can be hidden in Safari Reader?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I've got social links on my page. In reader mode, they're showing, and i want to hide them.
Social links block looks like this:

```
<div class="social-likes">
<span class="social-likes__item">
    <span class="social-likes__button" data-social="facebook">
        <svg class="social-likes__icon social-likes__icon_facebook"><use xlink:href="/images/m/svg/sprite.svg#social-likes__icon_facebook"></use></svg>
    </span>
    <span class="social-likes__counter">0</span>
</span>
<span class="social-likes__item">
    <span class="social-likes__button" data-social="vkontakte">
        <svg class="social-likes__icon social-likes__icon_vkontakte"><use xlink:href="/images/m/svg/sprite.svg#social-likes__icon_vkontakte"></use></svg>
    </span>
    <span class="social-likes__counter">0</span>
</span>
<span class="social-likes__item">
    <span class="social-likes__button" data-social="twitter">
        <svg class="social-likes__icon social-likes__icon_twitter"><use xlink:href="/images/m/svg/sprite.svg#social-likes__icon_twitter"></use></svg>
    </span>
    <span class="social-likes__counter">0</span>
</span>
```

Unfortunately, page content is loaded from DB, so i can only use some CSS or JS tricks (so page sourcecode  cannot be changed).

I've looked through [Safari Reader source code](https://github.com/adadgio/safari-reader-js/blob/master/safari-reader.src.beautified.js) and tried to add to social links container some class or id names, which marked in reader's code as 'negative' and should not be shown - for example, '*#disqus_thread*', '*.instapaper_ignore*' - with no results.
I've also tried this on test page (so this classes contained in page source code) - again, the same result.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.
Elements which should be hidden was wrapped in

`<aside class="instapaper_ignore">...</aside>`

Looks like reader algorithm gives different weights to tags.

Comment: Tried this in Safari 10.0.3 and it doesn't seem to work.